# How to export sharepoint management scripts' result to csv/text file

Tags: powershell, export, csv

```
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SharePoint”) > $null
 function EnumerateUserRolesPermissions ([string]$webURL){
 $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webURL)
 $web = $site.OpenWeb()
 $webUsers = $web.Users
 $groups = $web.sitegroups
 foreach($webUser in $webUsers){
 $Permissions = $web.Permissions
 foreach($group in $groups)
 {
 foreach($Permission in $Permissions){
 if($webUser.ID -eq $Permission.Member.ID){
 foreach ($role in $webUser.Roles){
 if ($role.Type -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleType]::None)
 {
 write-output $webURL,“;“,$webUser.LoginName,“;“,$webUser.Name,“;",$role.Type.ToString(),";",$webUser.groups
 }
 }
 }
 if($group.ID -eq $Permission.Member.ID){
 foreach ($role in $group.Roles){
 if ($role.Type -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleType]::None)
 {
 foreach($user in $group.users){
 write-output $webURL,“;“,$user.LoginName,“;“,$user.Name,“;",$role.Type.ToString(),";",$group.name
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
 function EnumerateSiteUsers ()
 {
 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
 $farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
 foreach ($spService in $farm.Services) {
 if (!($spService -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService])) {
 continue;
 }
 foreach ($webApp in $spService.WebApplications) {
 if ($webApp -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication]) { continue }
 $webAppUrl = $webApp.GetResponseUri('Default').AbsoluteUri
 foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) {
 foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
 EnumerateUserRolesPermissions $web.url
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
EnumerateSiteUsers
```

---

i am new to fairly new to sharepoint. i found this script that will list me all the sites and their users/groups in a farm. when i run this i get results in the manangment shell and its a long list. i am trying to get this export to a csv file. N i tried  adding export-csv at the end and its not working. I tried few other answers i found on google and i end up getting empty files.
Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this in PS but maybe the easiest is Out-File:

```
"$webURL,$($user.LoginName),$($user.Name),$($role.Type.ToString()),$($group.name)" | Out-File $logFile -Append
```

You could Create the file at the beginning of your script something like this (you may want to add a date stamp to the file name):

```
$log = "C:\path\to\log.csv"
if (!(Test-Path $log)) {
    $logFile = New-Item $log -ItemType file
    #add Headers if required:
    "WebUrl, UserName, Role, GroupName" | Out-File $logFile
}
else {
    Clear-Content $log
    $logFile = $log
    "WebUrl, UserName, Role, GroupName" | Out-File $logFile
}
```